# Cannot click element of Icon

Tags: jquery, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I'm kinda new to selenium and i have encounter an icon element which i cannot click. Please look at the details below.

[image]

Tried this relative xpath and still noElementException occured when im running my script.

```
.//*[@id='inforWsAppList']/li[2]/a
```

Appreciate all those who wil share their ideas thanks!

Tried the switch frame method and still no luck:

```
 WebElement iframeElement = driver.findElement(By.id("lid://infor.social.mingleinstance1")); // This is the iframe that you're saying 
        driver.switchTo().frame(iframeElement);
        driver.findElement(By.name(".//*[@id='inforWsAppList']/li[2]/a")).click();   // or [@id='inforWsAppList']/li[2] 
        driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
        //
```

Comment: Fixed! Just change my element to "//li[@class='normal']" and it was able click the icon. Still need to switch frames.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a closer look to where your element is located, you would notice an `iframe` as one of the parents. You need to *switch to that `iframe` first*.

Comment: Hi alecxe thanks for the response. I saw about switching to iframe, but i didn't know that its the same on my case.

Comment: @user3713453 yeah, there is definitely an iframe there - see the path in the breadcrumbs.

Comment: I don't see any iframe there. Can you be more specific?

Comment: @user3713453 at the top of your screenshot there is a path to the element. On the right of the path there is an `iframe`. In your code, before searching for the element, you need to switch to this iframe.

Comment: Oh i see, Okay i'll try doing that. Thank you! :)

Comment: Tried to do what you said and still no luck :( Please do look at my code above